# Error connecting to the backend of apache atlas

Tags: wso2, postman, apache-atlas

I try to manage Apache Atlas APIs using WSO2 API Manager, when trying a get request   like this for example :

```
http://{address_IP:port}/atlas/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/v2/entity/bulk
```

Postman gives

> 101503 error connecting to the backend

I just figured out that the production endpoint does not allow Http request.

What shall I do to fix that?

Comment: It seems the API gateway is unable reach the backend server. Check connctivity.

Comment: You have misunderstood what I said. I was referring to the gateway to backend connection.